# Why is self.age showing Attribute Error whilst the use of only age in condition allows the program to run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here, I made a condition that for the object to be created the age has to be greater than 18. For the condition, I used self.age as the age I'm referring to is that belonging from student_list.However, when I run the code, I'm getting :
AttributeError: 'student_list' object has no attribute 'age'

'''

```
class student_list:
    class_membership=True
    def __init__(self,name,age,miles):
        if self.age>=18:
            self.name=name
            self.age=age
            self.miles=miles

    def run(self):
        print(f'I ran {self.miles}')

    def name_1(self):
        print(f'Hi my name is {self.name}')

player_1=student_list('Tom Ellis',20,20)
print(player_1.name)
print(player_1.age)
```

'''

This error no longer shows when I use the following snippet:
'''

```
class student_list:
        class_membership=True
        def __init__(self,name,age,miles):
            if age>=18:
                self.name=name
                self.age=age
                self.miles=miles
```

'''

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: in your init you ask for self.age before you assign it any value

Answer (score 1):

when you create instance from `class student_list` function `__init__` is calling and in this fuction you shuold define variable and in this code you got error because before you don't define `self.age`.